# No access to ubuntu after restarting

Tags: boot

I have windows 8 pre-installed on my laptop. I downloaded ubuntu 12.04LS and installed it with wubi installer.But on restarting  windows 8 is loaded directly and I cant get access to ubuntu... will anyone please help me??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with UEFI. as you have win8 preinstalled, your system must have UEFI enabled and the secure boot prevents the ubuntu to handle the boot manager. most of times the problem solves with boo-repair. simply goto https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . I prefer 2nd option in that page. install boot-repair in live ubuntu boot and repair the boot manager.